# How to add Tabs to the TabLayout in latest Android Design Support Library

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-tablayout

I am new to android development. I following the tutorial http://slidenerd.com/2015/07/22/android-design-support-library/  which adds same fragment to the tablayout.But I need to add 3 unique fragments to the tablayout which download data from the web server.How to do that programming????
This is the code
     `
     package com.example.naveen.helloworld;

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
public class AppMainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private TabLayout mTablayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_main_screen2);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mTablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTablayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment =null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:                    return new Fragment();
            case 1:                    return new Fragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "News Feed";
            case 1:
                return "Events";
            default:
                return "News Feed";
        } }   }}`
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please post relevant code of what you've tried so far. You can't expect us to go through the tutorial to find the problem that you're stuck at

Comment: @akash93 added the code once check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `getItem` method inside the pager adapter sets the fragment so just modify the switch case to

```
switch(position){
   case 0: 
     return new NewsFragment();
   case 1: 
     return new EventsFragment();
}
```

Replace `NewsFragment` and `EventsFragment` with the corresponding fragments that you need to show

Comment: I  created two fragments named Fragment1,Fragment2 but Still getting an error.The error is "incompatible types:Required:android.support.v4.Fragment .but found   com.example.naveen.Sampleapp.Fragment1"  @akash93